# Fixed footer at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, fixed

I want a fixed footer at the bottom of my page where I'm able to have one line of text (all text centered), [just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SVx0.png).

[This is my current code](http://pastebin.com/T32XEk1F).

I've tried using other tutorials, but **none** have worked.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check the "Related" links to the right of this page.

Comment: Which tutorials have you tried and what problems did you run into?

Comment: All the tutorials tell you to set html and body to 100%. Doing that screws up my whole page by putting all of the content upwards.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Ryan Fait's sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). It can accomplish what you are trying to do with pure CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Content Here
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

.footer { /* centers the text */
    text-align: center; /* horizontal centering */
    line-height: 142px; /* vertical centering; should be equal to the footer height */
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is setting body and html to 100%. It screws up my whole page.

Comment: Why would your `body` and `html` have a height different than 100%?

Comment: When I set it to 100%, it pushes all of the content upwards. Look at the code I put in the original post.

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: It's the original CSS that comes with Bootstrap: [http://pastebin.com/yKwXe5AQ](http://pastebin.com/yKwXe5AQ)

Comment: The problem with this is that when I set body,html to height:100%, it moves all the content upwards (the hero-unit moves up under the navbar): [http://i.imgur.com/DdSQL37.png](http://i.imgur.com/DdSQL37.png)

Comment: Have you followed the HTML structure properly? The bootstrap has some divs outside of the container, and the footer is within the container. And have you changed the class names in the CSS or HTML to align with the Ryan Fait names/structure?

Comment: I've put all your CSS within html file just to test it for now and that hasn't worked. Could you try implementing it directly in my code (I'm probably missing something stupid as usual): [http://pastebin.com/T32XEk1F](http://pastebin.com/T32XEk1F)

Comment: The class names in the CSS that I posted do not fit with those of bootstrap. You need to customize it. I posted a very simple example from the Ryan Fait website to show you how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the footer element and the preceeding hr element like this:

```
<footer style="position:fixed; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;
      background:rgb(255,255,255); text-align:center;">
  <hr>
  <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
</footer>
```

I think this more or less solves your problem. It doesn't work exactly as the footer at http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/, but as far as I understand your question this is what you want.

PS: The CSS should of course be put in the CSS-file.