# Make footer of page stay at bottom with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a footer. I want this footer to always be at the bottom of the page. However, sometimes if an element above it is big, it doesnt go to the bottom. Does anyone have an idea how I can force the footer to always be at the bottom?

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
.footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
background-color:#151211;
line-height: 16px;
padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.footer .nav {
    float:left;
}
    .footer li {
        display:inline;
    }
    .footer li:before{
        color:#262320;
        content:" | ";
    }
    .footer li:first-child:before {
        content:"";
    }
.footer a:hover {
    color:#ffcc66;
}
.footer .nav a.login {
    background: url("../img/icon-lock.png") no-repeat 11px 5px #5c5a58;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #262320;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px 9px 8px 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.footer .nav a.login:hover {
    background-color: #939190;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}   
.copyright {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-align:right;
}
    .copyright span {
        color:#262320;
    }
```

And if it is useful, here is the html I am using:

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="liner">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://removed/ui/faces/login.xhtml" class="login">Client Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php" class="">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="termsofuse.php" class="">Terms of Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="privacy.php" class="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/removed/412357755542469" data-width="50" data-height="50" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true" style="top: 10px;"></div></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/removed" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @removed</a>
                        <script>!function(d, s, id) {
                                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
                                if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                                    js = d.createElement(s);
                                    js.id = id;
                                    js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                }
                            }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- .nav -->
            <p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2013  <span>|</span>removed</p>
        </div> <!-- .liner -->
    </div> <!-- .footer -->
```

Comment: create a fiddle if possible...

Comment: search maybe for `sticky footer`?

Answer (score 0):

You may find it valuable to take a look at some of answers posted to the following sticky-footer-related question: [Fixed footer at bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782437/fixed-footer-at-bottom-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

A sticky footer can be done with absolute positioning. You put the footer into a container, which uses 100% height and pin the footer at the bottom

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 25px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93RqS/)